# Activity indicator not loading correctly in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify({
        theme: {
            dark: true
        },
    }),

    data() {
        return {
            loading: null,
            requests: [{"req_id":78},{"req_id":79}],
            tableHeaders: [
                {
                    text: 'ID',
                    value: 'req_id',
                    align: 'center',
                },
                
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false, align: 'center'},
            ],

            createloading: false,
            cancelloading: false,

        };
    },
    methods: {

        createPacks(item) {
            this.loading = !this.loading;
            item.createloading = true;
        },

        excludeRequest(item) {
            this.loading =!this.loading;
            item.createloading = false;
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-row no-gutters class="align-start justify-start">
        <v-col>
           
            <v-row>      
                <v-data-table
                :headers="tableHeaders"
                :items="requests"
                :loading="loading" 
                >
                <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
                    <v-btn color="success" @click="createPacks(item)" :loading="item.createloading" :disabled="item.createloading">Create</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="error" @click="excludeRequest(item)" :loading="item.cancelloading" :disabled="!item.createloading">Cancel</v-btn>     
                </template>
                </v-data-table>
            </v-row>

            
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Please help me implement this code correctly, as it does not function correctly. The buttons should correctly show the loading indicator and should be independent.
Thank you in advance for your generosity.

Below is a link to codepen. 
https://codepen.io/protemir/pen/MWwGaeO

Comment: What's the problem? I can't see any error in the codepen

Comment: when I press the first create button then an indicator appears, then when I press the second create button after it, the indicator disappears

Comment: that's not happening when I try it... Both buttons are working fine